how to specify the author of commit created by revert() in JGit?
Suppose there is a file that is added and committed to a Git repository with the change reverted:
try (Git gitParent = Git.init().setDirectory(parentRepositoryRoot).call()) {
    final String fooName = "foo.txt";
    final String authorName = "foo";
    final String authorEmail = "<foo@example.com>";
    git.add().addFilepattern(fooName).call();
    RevCommit commit = git.commit().
        setMessage(comment).
        setAuthor(authorName, authorEmail).
        setAll(true).
        call();
    git.revert().include(commit).call();
}

The original commit has the author and e-mail specified. How does one specify these for the commit created by the RevertCommand ?

The git revert command itself does not have options for setting the committer name and email. Using the CLI, you can control these options via environment variables (GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL, GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL), but I don't know that this is applicable JGit.
